# Conditional Formatting in Excel 2016 minus blank cells

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get a column to highlight cells with duplicate values, but NOT the blank cells.  I have seen a lot of information for older Excel programs, but I'm working specifically with **Excel 2016**.

I have tried =COUNTIF, but I just can't seem to get it to work without error.  I know how to get Excel 2016 to highlight duplicates, just not while *also* excluding blank cells.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions you have!

Comment: What range are you trying to highlight? What is your `Applies to:` Range?  It is hard to give you a formula that will work for you without more information.

Comment: Sure!  I'm working with patient names and trying to highlight any patients with the same initials.  Column D = First name; Column E = Last name.  Column B = Initials, with the formula: =CONCATENATE(LEFT(D4,1),LEFT(E4,1)).
Column B is the one I want to have highlighted, cells B4 - B49.

Comment: `Applies to: $B$4:$B$49` formula: `=AND(COUNTIF(B:B,$B4)>1,$B4<>"")`

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple solution to this that doesn't involve formulas. Create two conditional formatting rules over the specific range, in the following order:

1. Cell Contains a blank value -> no formatting -> stop if true
2. Duplicate value -> custom formatting